# what's the relationship between dlfcn.c, ld-linux.so and libdl.so?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, dynamic-linking

I'm new to C and linker, sorry if my question sounds weird.

I check online and found `dlfcn.c`, `ld-linux.so` are both called dynamic linker, then comes the `libdl.so` which is dynamic linker library by its name, so what's the relationsip between them?

does `dlfcn.c` and other essentiaL .C files used to generate `ld-linux.so`? if yes then what's the difference between `ld-linux.so` and `libdl.so`?

Comment: The man page explains them:  https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux.so

Comment: `libdl.so` contains functions such as `dlopen()`, `dlclose()`, `dlsym()` for programs that load dynamic libraries _explicitly_ and look up the symbols by name to get pointers to  functions and objects in the library. A common use-case is a plug-in system. By contrast, `ld-linux.so` gets loaded by the kernel as the "interpreter" for a dynamically-linked ELF file to load dynamic libraries _implicitly_. This does the loading and dynamic linking before transferring control to the entry point of the ELF file. See the article [How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/).

Comment: @IanAbbott  Thanks for your answer. so can `libdl.so` also be called "dynamic linker"?

Comment: @amjad `libdl.so` dynamically links the dependencies of the library being opened by `dlopen()`. I'm not sure if it does that by itself (in which case it could be called a "dynamic linker") or if it relies on `ld-linux.so` to do the dynamic linking for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `ld-linux.so`

... is what I call "the dynamic linker":

This file is loaded by the Linux kernel together with an ELF file when the ELF file requires dynamic libraries.

The file `ld-linux.so` contains the code that loads the dynamic libraries (for example `libc.so`) needed by the ELF file from the disk to memory.

> `libdl.so`

This file is a dynamic library that contains functions like `dlopen()` or `dlsym()`:

These functions allow a program to "dynamically" load dynamic libraries - this means the program can call a function to load a dynamic library.

One of many use-cases are plug-ins that the user may configure in some configuration dialog (so these plug-ins do not appear in the list of required files stored inside the executable file).

> `dlfcn.c`

I'm not absolutely sure, but this file seems to be part of the source code of `libdl.so`.

Comment: could you have a look at this question please  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717392/why-the-dynamic-linker-couldnt-resolve-reference-when-a-share-library-has-a-dep